# W3 Total Cache Minify + cforms II = POST /wp-content/plugins/cforms/lib_ajax.php 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: plugin-w3-total-cache

Enabling minify is causing cforms (ajax enabled forms) to produce the following error on submit, whereby it hangs: **POST dearearth.net/wp-content/plugins/cforms/lib_ajax.php 500 (Internal Server Error)**

Current minify settings: http://loomn.it/baK

Form page: http://dearearth.net/contact

Any suggestions on how to get past this (aside from disabling minify altogether)?

Thanks!

Comment: Close-voted as *too localized*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe its a bug which is currently being attended to. Read the article below, which describes the current versions problems. [W3 Total Cache Minify Bug](http://wpcandy.com/reports/quick-fix-w3-total-cache-bug-in-most-recent-version)

Make sure that you've upgraded to the latest version in case its been resolved.

Comment: I am aware of the bug- I actually reverted to the previous version, which at least renders the rest of the site correctly...